# Cannot run the cURL command in Java

Tags: java, curl, get

I'm running this  below code in my java class and ideally it should return me a bearer token ....but when I run the code I get Exception.

The below is the code I'm running:

```
String[] command = {"curl","-v","-
X","POST","https://<Domain name>/oauth2/token","-H","cache-control: 
no-cache","-H","content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","-
H","postman-token: a1f5e569-cbc7-63cc-8667-45d85d74784b","-d","client_id=XXXXXXX","&","client_secret=XXXXXXXXXX","&","grant_type=client_credentials"};
for (String s: command)
            System.out.print(s); 
        ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command);
         Process p;
try {

                p = process.start();
     }
```

The exception I get is

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Can someone please let me know what was the issue or how to run the curl command from JAVA.

Comment: Is `curl` on `PATH`?

Comment: yes This the actual cURL command ` curl -v -X POST https://<Doman name>/oauth2/token -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'postman-token: a1f5e569-cbc7-63cc-8667-45d85d74784b' -d 'client_id=XXXX&client_secret=XXXXXX&grant_type=client_crede‌​ntials' `

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows or Mac?

Comment: I'm using Windows that err is when I ran it in Windows. But I'm using eclipse to run.

Also when I run it on linux machine my application is running but no result when the control reaches 
     p = process.start();
I mean its not going to next line
@gil.fernandes

Comment: Could you run this oneliner from Eclipse and see, if curl is indeed in the path: `new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/k", "path").redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT).start();` . This prints out the path in your environment.

Comment: @gil.fernandes yes it is returning the path in which my work space is in.

Comment: @Dee Have you checked, if the content of the path - you get on the console - contains the path to the curl executable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Rest Assured Framework? I had same requirements sometime back and could achieve it using Rest Assured.

```
RestAssured.baseURI = CURLURL;
Response r = (Response) given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().contentType("application/json").body(curlRequest)
.when().post("");
return r.getBody().asString();
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't understand can you help me with a little more detailed code